# Doesn't recognize MEDIA_BUTTON Trigger on Beats Solo

Tags: android, media

I tried both the Intent-receiver and the onKeyDown Method. Both work fine for most buttons but the Beats Solo Headset has multiple Buttons and only the Play Button is detected, the + / - Buttons don't trigger the Receiver nor they trigger onKeyDown().

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that these are supposed to work on Android? For example, is there some advertising or something indicating that these buttons work with Beats-enabled HTC devices? I mean, I can probably create a headset with a "stir-fry" button, but that does not mean that pressing it will trigger anything inside Android. :-)

Comment: they don't work with android thats why I write the app ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem in the AOSP Tech Specs. There are a lot of HID Interactions that aren't defined for Android. So I will try to read out the HID code with a scope and map this Key to Android.

[Android AOSP // KEYBOARD](http://source.android.com/tech/input/keyboard-devices.html)

EDIT: I connected them to the scope while a menu button press is clearly visible, the + amplitude is pretty small and - is nearly indetectable. I attached both scope screenshots. If anyone has found a solution then contact me please.

NOTE: the screenshot shows the menu button pressed 3 times!

[image: + Button press]

[image: Menu button press - 3 times]